# Handling threads for multiprocessing

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, windows-services

I'm experiencing an issue managing threads on .Net 4.0 C#, and my knowledge of threads is not sufficient to solve it, so I've post it here expecting that somebody could give me some piece of advise please.

The scenario is the following:

We have a Windows service on C# framework 4.0 that (1)connects via socket to a server to get a .PCM file, (2)then convert it to a .WAV file, (3)send it via Email - SMTP and finally (4)notify the initial server that it was successfully sent.

The server where the service had been installed has 8 processors and 8 GB or RAM.

To allow multiprocessing I've built the service with 4 threads, each one of them performs each task I mentioned previously.

On the code, I have classes and methods for each task, so I create threads and invoke methods as follows:

```
 Thread eachThread = new Thread(object.PerformTask);
```

Inside each method I'm having a While that checks if the connection of the socket is alive and continue fetching data or processing data depending on their porpuse.

```
while (_socket.Connected){ 
//perform task
}
```

The problem is that as more services are being installed (the same windows service is replicated and pointed between two endpoints on the server to get the files via socket) the CPU consumption increases dramatically, each service continues running and processing files but there is a moment were the CPU consumption is too high that the server just collapse.

The question is: what would you suggest me to handle this scenario, I mean in general terms what could be a good approach of handling this highly demanded processing tasks to avoid the server to collapse in CPU consumption?

Thanks.

PS.: If anybody needs more details on the scenario, please let me know.

**Edit 1**

With CPU collapse I mean that the server gets too slow that we have to restart it.

**Edit 2**

Here I post some part of the code so you can get an idea of how it's programmed:

```
while(true){
            //starting the service    
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint endPoint = conn.SettingConnection();
                string id = _objProp.Parametros.IdApp;

                using (socket = conn.Connect(endPoint))
                {
                    while (!socket.Connected)
                    {
                        _log.SetLog("INFO", "Conectando socket...");
                        socket = conn.Connect(endPoint);

                        //if the connection failed, wait 5 seconds for a new try.
                        if (!socket.Connected)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        }
                    }

                    proInThread = new Thread(proIn.ThreadRun);
                    conInThread = new Thread(conIn.ThreadRun);
                    conOutThread = new Thread(conOut.ThreadRun);

                    proInThread.Start();
                    conInThread.Start();
                    conOutThread.Start();

                    proInThread.Join();
                    conInThread.Join();
                    conOutThread.Join();
                }
          }
     }
```

**Edit 3**

- Thread 1

  > while (_socket.Connected)
  >               {
  >                   try
  >                   {
  >                       var conn = new AppConection(ref _objPropiedades);
  >
  > ```
  >                 try
  >                 {
  >                     string message = conn.ReceiveMessage(_socket);
  >                     lock (((ICollection)_queue).SyncRoot)
  >                     {
  >                         _queue.Enqueue(message);
  >                         _syncEvents.NewItemEvent.Set();
  >                         _syncEvents.NewResetEvent.Set();
  >                     }
  >                     lock (((ICollection)_total_rec).SyncRoot)
  >                     {
  >
  >                         _total_rec.Add("1");
  >                     }
  >                 }
  >                 catch (SocketException ex)
  >                 {
  >                     //log exception
  >
  >                 }
  >                 catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
  >                 {
  >                     //log exception
  >                 }
  >                 catch (Exception ex)
  >                 {
  >                    //log exception
  >
  >                 }
  >                 //message received
  >
  >             }
  >             catch (Exception ex)
  >             {
  >                //logging error
  >             }
  >         }
  >
  >         //release ANY instance that could be using memory
  >         _socket.Dispose();
  >         log = null;
  > ```
- Thread 2

  > while (_socket.Connected)
  >               {
  >                       try{
  >                           _syncEvents.NewItemEventOut.WaitOne();
  >
  > ```
  >                     if (_socket.Connected)
  >                     {
  >                         lock (((ICollection)_queue).SyncRoot)
  >                         {
  >
  >                             total_queue = _queue.Count();
  >
  >                         }
  >
  >                         int i = 0;
  >                         while (i < total_queue)
  >                         {
  >                             //EMail Emails;
  >                             string mail = "";
  >                             lock (((ICollection)_queue).SyncRoot)
  >                             {
  >
  >                                 mail = _queue.Dequeue();
  >
  >                                 i = i + 1;
  >                             }
  >                             try
  >                             {
  >                                 conn.SendMessage(_socket, mail);
  >                                 _syncEvents.NewResetEvent.Set();
  >                             }
  >                             catch (SocketException ex)
  >                             {
  >                                 //log exception
  >                             }
  >                         }
  >                     }
  >                     else
  >                     {
  >                         //log exception
  >
  >                         _syncEvents.NewAbortEvent.Set();
  >                         Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
  >                     }
  >                 }
  >                 catch (InvalidOperationException e)
  >                 {
  >                     //log exception
  >                 }
  >                 catch (Exception e)
  >                 {
  >                     //log exception
  >                 }
  >         }
  >
  >         //release ANY instance that could be using memory
  >         _socket.Dispose();
  >         conn = null;
  >         log = null;
  > ```
- Thread 3

  > while (_socket.Connected)
  >                   {
  >
  > ```
  >                 int total_queue = 0;
  >                 try
  >             {
  >                 _syncEvents.NewItemEvent.WaitOne();
  >                 lock (((ICollection) _queue).SyncRoot)
  >                 {
  >                     total_queue = _queue.Count();
  >                 }
  >                 int i = 0;
  >                 while (i < total_queue)
  >                 {
  >                     if (mgthreads.GetThreatdAct() <
  > ```
  >
  > mgthreads.GetMaxThread())
  >                           {
  >                               string message = "";
  >                               lock (((ICollection) _queue).SyncRoot)
  >                               {
  >
  > ```
  >                             message = _queue.Dequeue();
  >                             i = i + 1;
  >
  >                         }
  >                         count++;
  >                         lock (((ICollection) _queueO).SyncRoot)
  >                         {
  >                             app.SetParameters(_socket, _id,
  > ```
  >
  > message, _queueO, _syncEvents,
  >   _total_Env, _total_err);
  >                               }
  >
  > ```
  >                         Thread producerThread = new
  > ```
  >
  > Thread(app.ThreadJob) { Name =
  >   "ProducerThread_" +
  >   DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss"),
  >   Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
  >   };
  >                               producerThread.Start();
  >
  > ```
  >                         producerThread.Join();
  >
  >                         mgthreads.IncThreatdAct(producerThread);
  >                     }
  >                     mgthreads.DecThreatdAct();
  >                 }
  >                 mgthreads.DecThreatdAct();
  >             }
  >             catch (InvalidOperationException e)
  >             {
  >
  >             }
  >             catch (Exception e)
  >             {
  >
  >             }
  >             Thread.Sleep(500);
  >         }
  >
  >         //release ANY instance that could be using memory
  >         _socket.Dispose();
  >         app = null;
  >         log = null;
  >         mgthreads = null;
  > ```
- Thread 4

  > MessageVO mesVo =
  >   fac.ParseMessageXml(_message);

Comment: Can you define "server CPU consumption collapse"?

Comment: And can you define what you mean by "The problem is that as more services are being installed ". Does this mean more threads are running or more processes? How does a thread determine what task to perform?

Comment: Can you define how many "more" is. Most of your threads sounds like serial operations to me or do you handle many of them in one service?

Comment: Please read Edit 1 and 2. I mean we replicate the service 10 times more (10 installations) pointing to different IP addresses.

Comment: If you are comfortable with posting more code I will look at it. I would need the code of the 3 thread procs.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I added the code of each thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would lower the thread priority and have all threads pass through a Semaphore that limits concurrency to Environment.ProcessorCount. This not a perfect solution but it sounds like it is enough in this case and an easy fix.

Edit: Thinking about it, you have to fold the 10 services into one single process because otherwise you won't have centralized control about the threads that are running. If you have 10 independent processes they cannot coordinate.

Comment: this is very useful, if your tasks actually require long periods of pure cpu calculation.

Comment: The code you posted does not look like it will needlessly spin. I could not find a problem with it. Do this: Run the service until it is hot, then stop the debugger and look at all running theards and their callstacks. You will probably find something interesting. At the very least you will find the hot spot.

Comment: I took your suggestion about the debugger and I realized that theres a problem with the connection, the fact is that if the server for any reason closes the endpoint, the service begins to loop trying to reconnect (causing more CPU usage). How should I handle it?

Comment: You can do two thing: a) fail and log b) retry N times and then fail and log. I guess b) is not an option because if the connection is lost, the server will have lost it too causing it to loose any state associated with the connection. I recommend that you fail, log, and retry the whole transaction/message as a whole (not only reestablish the connection). Retry 5 times with a delay of (1 << i) seconds and then send yourself an email so you notice problems.

Comment: I have to warn you: Do not rely on Isconnected to return a reliable value. If it returns true, a single CPU-cycle later it might return false causing your read/write call to crash. Here is a trick: Would your program be safe if IsConnected was implemented as (random.GetNextBool())? It must be safe to assume complete garbage output from this property. You can only use it as a perf optimization, not for reliability.

Comment: And I advise you to check this code: catch (InvalidOperationException e). If you want to learn why it is deeply wrong, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There should normally be no collapse because of high cpu usage. While any of the threads is waiting for something remote to happen (for instance for the remote server to response to the request), that thread uses no cpu resource. But while it is actually doing something, it uses cpu accordingly. In the Task you mentioned, there is no inherent high cpu usage (as the saving of PCM file as WAV requires no complex algorithm), so the high cpu usage seems to be a sign of an error in programming.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew that.